# Best Buy marked a computer down from $\$4,500.00$ to $\$3,300.00$. What was the total percent markdown based on its original price?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I've tried doing this problem several ways and I can't seem to achieve the given answer of $41.3\%$.

Answer (score 5):

That given answer is just wrong, in an inexplicable way. It would fit if that were a markdown from \$4600 to \$2700, but not any smaller round numbers.